# Why does my hashset contain duplicates?

Tags: java, hashset

When I create a hashset for my elements, for some reason I can add duplicate elements to it. I did override the equals and hashcode methods. Underneath is a bit of my code and an example of my problem. For simplicity I named my elements "element".

```
set.add(new element(new Point2D.Double(0,1), new Point2D.Double(2, 3), true));
set.add(new element(new Point2D.Double(0,1), new Point2D.Double(2, 3), true));
for (element e : set)
    System.out.println("set element : " + e.firstPoint2D.toString() 
                                    + e.secondPoint2D.toString() 
                                    + e.lastBoolean 
                                    + " and hashcode = " + e.hashCode());
```

this returns :

```
set element : Point2D.Double[0.0, 1.0] Point2D.Double[2.0, 3.0] true 
and hashcode = 3211
set element : Point2D.Double[0.0, 1.0] Point2D.Double[2.0, 3.0] true 
and hashcode = 3211
```

We clearly see they have the same hashcode, so why are they both in the hashset? I thought a hashset's utility was in the fact that it couldn't contain duplicates? Am I missing something? Here is equals and hashcode :

```
public boolean equals(element e) {
    if (this.firstPoint2D.equals(e.firstPoint2D) && 
     this.secondPoint2D.equals(e.secondPoint2D) && 
     this.lastBoolean == e.lastBoolean)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int result = (int)(firstPoint2D.getX() + 10*firstPoint2D.getY() 
     + 100*secondPoint2D.getX() + 1000*secondPoint2D.getY());
    if (lastBoolean)
        return result + 1;
    else
        return result;
}
```

Comment: Could you post the `equals` method for `Point2D.Double`? You problem is likely there - in `Point2D.hashCode` you manually generate the `hashCode` for `Point2D.Double`, but in the `Point2D.equals` you rely on `Point2D.Double.equals` - this is likely wrong.

Comment: Try adding `@Override` to your equals method. Always.

Comment: @BoristheSpider I suspect OP is using `java.awt.geom.Point2D.Double`.

Comment: @Pshemo just saw your comment, that's certainly the problem. I didn't even notice... Oops. Either way, mixing external and internal `equals` and `hashCode` is odd.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `equals` method is not correctly overridden and hence, it uses `equals()` method of `Object` class rather than the overridden version. `equals()` method ob `Object` class accepts an `Object` argument whereas the one you have overridden accepts `element`, following should work:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object e) {
    if ( e instanceof element &&
    this.firstPoint2D.equals(((element)e).firstPoint2D) && 
     this.secondPoint2D.equals(((element)e).secondPoint2D) && 
     this.lastBoolean == ((element)e).lastBoolean)
        return true;
    else
        return false;
}
```

[Here](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals(java.lang.Object))'s javadoc for `equals()`.

Comment: No more duplications now ! Thanks